# JXDatePicker questions (part 2)

Tags: java, swing, swingx, jcalendar

I want to ask some questions about jxdatepicker:

(1) I write the following code to change the date format:

```
public test(){
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd");
    jxDatePicker1.setFormats(dateFormat);
}
```

When I run my gui, the datepicker is show today date (2015-03-03) but when I click yesterday date, it goes to another date (2015-12-28) not the yesterday date. What happened to my code?

(2) How to change the header title color?

(3) How to change the color of the selected date?

[image]

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Your date format is wrong, it should be `yyyy-MM-dd`, check the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) when in doubt

Comment: Argh... you solved my problem again. The date format that I put is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The date format is wrong, it should be `yyyy-MM-dd`
2. Use `JXDatePicker#getMonthView#setMonthStringBackground`
3. Use `JXDatePicker#getMonthView#setSelectionBackground`.  If you want to change the color use to "highlight" today, you can also use `JXDatePicker#getMonthView#setTodayBackground` - but it only colors the border of the box when today is not highlighted...

[image]